Can equation from paper "Item-based Collaborative Filtering Recommendation Algorithms" be used for implicit feedback?
Article Item-based Collaborative Filtering Recommendation Algorithms by Badrul Sarwar, George Karypis, Joseph Konstan, and John Riedl gives this equation:
$$P_{u,i} = \frac{\sum_{j}^S s_{i,j} * R_{u,j}}{\sum_{j}^S s_{i,j}}  $$
for predicting how users will rate items based on similiar items, where
$s_{i,j}$ is similarity between i and j
$S$ are all items similiar to i
$R_{u,j}$ is rating user u gave to item j
Can this equation be used for implicit feedback, where binary values (1 if user interacted with item and 0 if not) will take place of user rating?
